# How to create a div with arrow and divider for content such that they are aligned using react and css?

Tags: css, reactjs

i want to create a div with arrow under the button as seen in picture below,

[image]

the div with arrow should be just in the center of the button. the content in the div is seperated with the divider.

Now the problem is when the number in the Available component increases the divider moves out of sync with the arrow and the arrow also should be in the center of the click button like in pic whatever the number is.

here is the example of my code in code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-bush-mj7lz?file=/src/styles.css:0-1202

below is my code,

```
function Parent() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="flex_wrapper">
                <button> click </button>
                <div className="box">
                    <BoxContent />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

function BoxContent() {
    return (
        <div className="box_content_wrapper">
            {true && (
                <>
                    <Available />
                    <div className="spacing" />
                    <span>
                        Available <br />
                        <span className="sub_text">some text</span>
                    </span>
                    <div className="divider" />
                </>
            )}
            <Available />
            <div className="spacing" />
            <span>
                Available <br />
                <span className="sub_text">some text</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    );
}

function Available() {
    return (
        <div className="view">
            <span>10</span> //when i change these values to any big number also i want the divider 
            //and the arrow to be 
            //in just below each other
            <span>/100</span> //when i change these values to any big number also i want the divider 
            //and the arrow to be in just below each other
        </div>
    ); 
}




below is my css,

.wrapper {
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 4;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    position: relative;
}

.flex_wrapper {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
 } 

 .box {
     padding: 16px;
     height: 61px;
     border-radius: 8px;
     border: 1px solid black;
     background-color: white;
     position: absolute;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     top: 72px;
     left: 35px;
 }

 .box::after {
     content: "";
     width: 0px;
     height: 0px;
     position: absolute;
     background-color: black;
     top: -4px;
     left: 141px;
     border-left: 8px solid;
     border-left-color: #fff;
     border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
     border-top: 8px solid transparent;
     transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
 }

 .box_content_wrapper {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     align-items: center;
 }

 .view {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     align-items: baseline;
     margin-top: 8px; 
  }

  .sub_text {
      white-space: nowrap;
  }

  .spacing {
      width: 8px;
  }

  .divider {
      height: 37px;
      margin-left: 16px;
      margin-right: 16px;
      border: 1px solid grey;
  }
```

could someone help me with this. thanks.
how can i have the available container centered with arrow.

Answer (score 1):

As Drew Reese mentioned "This only works if the content is the same on both sides of the divider." So probably you should make the structure of your box like:

```html
<div>
   <div style="flex:1;"></div>
   <span class="separator"></span>
   <div style="flex:1;"></div>
</div>
```

Below you will find correction for your arrow. I used border instead of background to make arrow as you wish and then centered it using `left: 50%;` and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(225deg);`

Code:

```css
.box::after {
  content: "";
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  top: -1px;
  left: 50%;
  /*border-left: 8px solid;*/
  border-left-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(225deg);
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Same/similar fix as mine, but got the border issue straightened out before I could on mine. This is answer.

Comment: Sure there is not 100 way to center, but the center is the easy part. I still give you credit in my answer :-)